# Get Facebook Login Token from another App

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Is it possible to get facebook access token from an app that does not belong to me? I mean I want to spoof a iOS app's FB Login.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible if you can somehow access the internal of that application, i would said a rooted android or jail broke iphone could allow that . Although i doubt if it will be of any use as access token expire fast.. well unless you know the app secret too.

You should register your own app on Facebook developers, its not that hard.